# How to repair a drain line broken flush with a slab

Tags: plumbing, concrete, drain, slab

Ok so I have two drain lines going down into my slab that are broken flush or darn close to being broken off flush with the slab. I bought a hammer drill and was going to break around the drain rougly 2 to 4 inches deep and then I was going to couple the pipe with these rubber couplings and fill in whatever I broke out with this hydrolic cement. Am I right by doing what I am doing or should I go a different route? Any advice is greatly appreciated and I say thanks in advance.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: What are these drains for? If they are toilets, there are special repair flanges available that have an expanding washer that seals the new flange to the inside of the existing pipe. There may be similar repair options for other types of pipe too.

Comment: One of these is a drain for a very small bathroom sink and the other will be a drain line for a washing machine.

Answer (score 1):

The rubber couplings can be considered a temporary repair. As such they should not be partially buried in concrete.

The really correct fix here is to remove existing concrete to the point that a proper connection can be made to the existing piping that can bear up to being a permanent type fix that can be embedded in the replacement concrete.

Comment: Permanent fix being what a soddered joint?

Comment: what is `soddered` ? i don't think that is a real word.

Comment: Soldered or however ya have to say it

Comment: Soldered joint = permanent fix. It would probably be easier to get a good solid joint that close to the floor if it were brazed. That said copper pipes should be in sleeves, when in concrete, being solidly encased in concrete is generally not a good idea for the reason you are dealing with now

Comment: Well sounds like I have no other options no? So I should solder the pipes back together after I chip out the concrete.